# ddclient updating to local IP instead of public IP

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns, dynamic-dns

I'm trying to setup ddclient on my ubuntu server to update my DNS records on zoneedit for when my public IP changes.

It's updating fine, the problem is that it's giving zoneedit my local IP instead of my public one.

```
SUCCESS:  updating mydomain.com: IP address set to 192.168.0.17 (200: Update succeeded.)
```

My ddclient config file looks like this:

```
protocol=zoneedit1
use=if, if=eth0
server=dynamic.zoneedit.com
login='user'
password='password'
mydomain.com
```

Why is it updating to my local IP instead of my public one?

**Update:** could this be because I'm behind a router? If so, how should I configure ddclient to get the public IP?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, the issue is because you're behind a router. The best solution would be to see if you can install a ddns client on the router itself. Otherwise there are ddns update tools that finger a remote server and ascertain your IP by what this yields.

This can be done by replacing:

```
use=if, if=eth0
```

With this:

```
use=web, web=checkip.dyndns.org/
```

Which is apparently the default configuration generated by `debconf` on Debian systems.

Comment: ah - thanks. I presumed ddclient would use a remote server to get the IP, if anyone knows how to set this up that would be great.

Comment: now solved - see my answer

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
use=if, if=eth0
```

with

```
use=web, web=my.ip.fi/
```

Comment: What does this do? Would you add some information or context as to *why* this is a solution?

Comment: my.ip.fi just displays your current ip adress without the "Your current Ip Adress is:..." thing. So you can CURL it too

Comment: Please add that information to your answer and an example of how it's different than the already accepted answer, otherwise it just looks like a duplicate answer with a different site.

Comment: http://icanhazip.com/ also only displays IP

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `web=dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/getip` to get it working

```
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf

use=if, if=eth0
use=web, web=dynamicdns.park-your-domain.com/getip
ssl=yes
protocol=googledomains
login=myLoginCredentials
password='myPwdContent'
myGoogleDomain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

My DDNS provider, no-ip.com, doesn't require the second (web=..) parameter. Just replacing the line with `use=if` with `use=web` worked for me.