# SSH into Linux machine over internet

Tags: linux, ssh, dynamic-ip

I recently setup a Linux machine in my dorm and I would like to be able to access it via SSH. I'm on a college campus that has several subnets to manage the machines connected wirelessly to the network. Because of this, the subnet of the machines and their IP changes frequently.

Since the machines will likely be on different subnets, I can't SSH by entering the IP address. Is there any way to set up SSH via an internet service or something similar that would forward me to my machine?

Comment: Do you need to access it from outside the campus network? Or just internally (from within the campus network)?

Comment: I need it internally, but I figured that since I'll be on a different subnet it will pose similar issues as accessing it from off-campus.

Comment: There is likely a firewall blocking inbound connections from the outside Internet. Internally, you might see if your campus network gives a DNS name for connected clients. My campus maps computers that request an IP into a DNS name with the format `%machine_name%.dynamic.%college_name%.edu`. Perhaps your network has something like that?

Comment: I get a similar address when I do a "host <ip>". I'll give it a try when I get off work and see if that gets me anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: The one issue that I occasionally run into is that it doesn't update immediately when the computer moves around. That shouldn't be an issue on a machine that stays in the same place.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [Log me in Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/labs/#HamachiforLinux).

I use it on a Linux server thats behind NAT with no way of forwarding ports. It's free as in beer.

You setup a network on logmein.com then install the client on the server. This will create a `ham0` network device with an IP that will never change. You need to connect your client machines to the same hamachi network and you can ssh to your box by it's hamachi ip.

Comment: Perfect! I've used Hamachi when I was a kid for gaming purposes, but I completely forgot about it now. I'll give it a try soon. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use no-ip.com or dyndns.com.

This question may have your answer [ddclient updating to local IP instead of public IP](https://superuser.com/questions/389125/ddclient-updating-to-local-ip-instead-of-public-ip)

You don't specify if you need to access from the subnet or internet. So the solution is different (both explained in the superuser.com link)