# ddclient updating to public IP instead of private IP

Tags: networking, bash, dhcp, dynamic-dns, private-network

This is the antithesis to [question 389125](https://superuser.com/questions/389125/ddclient-updating-to-local-ip-instead-of-public-ip)

I have *private* services (apache, ssh, synergys for example) accessible on a desktop on the local network. This is not with centralised login (ldap/AD for example) and there is also no automatic A record being created by the DHCP service (though that might be a good thing to implement anyway). The desktop does not have Samba installed either.

I have ddclient installed and had it configured with:

> use=if, if=eth0

This worked well for a long time - but every now and again this updates the record to the *public* IP address of our Internet connection - which is rather useless. So I resorted to this:

```
use=cmd,                     cmd=/usr/local/sbin/getip
login=<mylogin>
password=<mypassword>
server=freedns.afraid.org
protocol=freedns
<zatricky.dynamic-host-address>
```

The "getip" script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
ip addr show dev eth0 | grep inet\  | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/\/.*//'
```

This script *always* returns the correct IP address. Yet the IP address is *still* erroneously changed to the public IP by ddclient/freedns.

Is there a known problem? Am I doing this right?

Comment: I wasn't even aware you could do this.  Wouldn't it be easier to issue a static IP via dhcp then add a local dns entry for the server?

Comment: @Paul agreed. I did not even know this was possible. And if you don't want to or can't update local dns, why not at least put an entry in your `hosts` file with the static ip?

Comment: Good thoughts. In both cases, the issue is with some assumptions.

1) That I am the network administrator. At home or an office I manage, this can work 100%. Somewhere else, it depends on someone else setting up their DHCP/DNS correctly.

2) Setting hosts entries - this needs to be set on every computer that might want to access the host. This might be done over VPN or from any number of clients. DNS is far more convenient.